# Running VBA code and getting a Run Time error '91'

Tags: excel, vba

When I run the below code I get a run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set.  It highlights the coding underneath the number for in the set rng function,  Anyone know what I need to do to the code for it not to error out?

```
' Global and Public Variables
Dim i As Integer
Dim FilterProducts() As String

'Option Explicit

Private Sub btnOK_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' Declare variables:
Dim rng As Range
Dim index As Integer
Dim totalLocations As Integer
totalLocations = 0

' Check to see if at least one Product is selected:
If ListBox2.ListCount = 0 Then

    MsgBox "Please select at least one product line from the list!", vbCritical, "Error"

Else

    ' Filter out the pivot table based on the selections.

    ' 1) Find out the size remaining in ListBox1, and assign that to the size of the array.
    ReDim FilterProducts(ListBox1.ListCount)

    ' 2) Fill up the values in the array with the ones remaining in the List Box1.
    For index = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1

        FilterProducts(index) = ListBox1.List(index)

    Next

    ' 3) Filter out the pivot table on wsDbPGPivot to only the values selected:
    FilterChartOnProducts ("Chart 1")
'    FilterChartOnProducts ("Chart 2")
'    FilterChartOnProducts ("Chart 3")
'    FilterChartOnProducts ("Chart 4")
'    FilterChartOnProducts ("Chart 5")
'    FilterChartOnProducts ("Chart 6")
'    FilterChartOnProducts ("Chart 7")
'    FilterChartOnProducts ("Chart 8")
'    FilterChartOnProducts ("Chart 9")
'    FilterChartOnProducts ("Chart 10")
'    FilterChartOnProducts ("Chart 11")
'    FilterChartOnProducts ("Chart 12")
'    FilterChartOnProducts ("Chart 13")
'    FilterChartOnProducts ("Chart 14")
'    FilterChartOnProducts ("Chart 15")
'    FilterChartOnProducts ("Chart 16")
'    FilterChartOnProducts ("Chart 17")
'    'FilterChartOnProducts ("Chart 18")
'    FilterChartOnProducts ("Chart 22")

    ' 4) Update Number of Locations:
    For index = 0 To ListBox2.ListCount - 1

        ' Find the range for the current Product:
        wsDataAll.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=ListBox2.List(index)
        Set rng = Range(wsDataAll.Cells.Find(ListBox2.List(index), LookAt:=xlWhole).Offset(0, 14), wsDataAll.Cells.Find(ListBox2.List(index), LookAt:=xlWhole).Offset(0, 14).End(xlDown))

        totalLocations = totalLocations + CountUnique(rng)

    Next

    ' 5) Write the results:
    wsDistributorbyProductGroup.Range("S8").Value = totalLocations

    ' 6) Clear the filter from the table:
    wsDataAll.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1

End If

' Go back to main worksheet
wsDistributorbyProductGroup.Activate

Unload Product

End Sub
Sub FilterChartOnProducts(NameOfChart As String)

Dim index As Integer

 ' First make sure all of the current filters are reset:
wsDbPGPivot.ChartObjects(NameOfChart).Activate
ActiveChart.PivotLayout.PivotTable.PivotFields("PRODUCT_GROUP").ClearAllFilters

' Then, go through the Products not selected and make them not visible (or filtered out):
For index = 0 To UBound(FilterProducts) - 1

    ActiveChart.PivotLayout.PivotTable.PivotFields("PRODUCT_GROUP").PivotItems(FilterProducts(index)).Visible = False

    Next

End Sub
Public Function CountUnique(rng As Range) As Integer
    Dim dict As Dictionary
    Dim cell As Range
    Set dict = New Dictionary
    For Each cell In rng.Cells
         If Not dict.Exists(cell.Value) Then
            dict.Add cell.Value, 0
        End If
    Next
    CountUnique = dict.Count
End Function
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
     For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
         ListBox1.Selected(i) = True
     Next i
End If

If CheckBox1.Value = False Then
     For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
         ListBox1.Selected(i) = False
     Next i
End If

End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox2_Click()
If CheckBox2.Value = True Then
     For i = 0 To ListBox2.ListCount - 1
         ListBox2.Selected(i) = True
     Next i
End If

If CheckBox2.Value = False Then
     For i = 0 To ListBox2.ListCount - 1
         ListBox2.Selected(i) = False
     Next i
End If

End Sub


Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
     If ListBox1.Selected(i) = True Then ListBox2.AddItem ListBox1.List(i)
Next i

For i = Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
    If ListBox1.Selected(i) = True Then
    Me.ListBox1.RemoveItem i
    End If
Next i

End Sub


Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

For i = 0 To ListBox2.ListCount - 1
     If ListBox2.Selected(i) = True Then ListBox1.AddItem ListBox2.List(i)
Next i

For i = ListBox2.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
    If ListBox2.Selected(i) = True Then
    ListBox2.RemoveItem i
    End If
Next i

End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()
ListBox1.MultiSelect = 0
 ListBox2.MultiSelect = 0

End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton2_Click()
ListBox1.MultiSelect = 1
 ListBox2.MultiSelect = 1

End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton3_Click()
ListBox1.MultiSelect = 2
 ListBox2.MultiSelect = 2

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim myList As Collection
    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim myVal As Variant


    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Locations")
    Set myRange = ws.Range("Q2", ws.Range("Q2").End(xlDown))
    Set myList = New Collection

    On Error Resume Next
    For Each myCell In myRange.Cells
    myList.Add myCell.Value, CStr(myCell.Value)
    Next myCell
    On Error GoTo 0

    For Each myVal In myList
    Me.ListBox1.AddItem myVal
    Next myVal


OptionButton1.Value = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you remove all the unnecessary code leaving the bit with the issue so the example is readable?

Comment: I removed all except where the problem is occurring.  Let me know if I removed too much      Dim i As Integer
                Set rng = Range(wsDataAll.Cells.Find(ListBox2.List(index), LookAt:=xlWhole).Offset(0, 14), wsDataAll.Cells.Find(ListBox2.List(index), LookAt:=xlWhole).Offset(0, 14).End(xlDown))

Answer (score 1):

You should test that the search value is actually found before you try and use properties of the found range:

```
Set rng = wsDataAll.Cells.Find(ListBox2.List(index), LookAt:=xlWhole)
If not rng Is Nothing then
   Set rng = Range(rng.Offset(0, 14), rng.Offset(0, 14).End(xlDown))
Else
   Msgbox ListBox2.List(index) & " not found"
   Exit Sub
End If
```

for example.

Comment: I tried this.  You were right, it wasn't finding the data.  I changed the index to 1 instead of 0.  It is finding the data but not calculating the total locations.